# How to create links in netlogo from ArcGIS shapefile

Tags: hyperlink, undefined, nodes, netlogo

I have successfully loaded other ArcGIS shapefiles e.g., river polygon.However I am trying to draw/ create links by loading a polyline shapefile. Here is an extract of the code.

```
set river_area gis:load-dataset "River_data/April_28_2018_800m_Lines.shp"
set river_zones gis:load-dataset "River_data/May 5 2018_River_polygon_Zones.shp"
set polylines_links gis:load-dataset "River_data/Milford_Possible_routes_Polylines.shp"
```

Below is the code (from another source)for creating links and nodes. How can I modify it to work on the code that I am developing ?

```
foreach polylines-of polylines_links node-precision [
    (foreach butlast ? butfirst ? [ if ?1 != ?2 [      
let n1 new-node-at first ?1 last ?1
      let n2 new-node-at first ?2 last ?2
      ask n1 [create-link-with n2]
    ]])
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for. Happy coding!

```
foreach polylines-of polylines_links node-precision [
    x ->
    (foreach  butlast x butfirst x  [
      [a b] ->  if  a != b
      [
       let n1 new-node-at first a last a
       let n2 new-node-at first b last b
        ask n1 [create-link-with n2]
      ]
    ])
  ]
```